# TinyMCE 4 insertContent(); not behaving correctly

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I got a TinyMCE editor instance running. And

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"></div><div class="col-md-6"></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"></div></div>');
```

This should generate :

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"></div><div class="col-md-6"></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"></div></div>
```

But instead of that it is generating:

```
<div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
```

When I am doing it step by step :

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent('<div class="row">&nbsp;');
tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent('<div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;</div>');
tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent('<div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;</div>');
tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent('&nbsp;</div>');
tinyMCE.activeEditor.insertContent('<div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div></div>');
```

It gets me an even more curious result

```
<div class="row">&nbsp;
<div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;
<div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What am I missing??? Should I use another tag instead of **insertContent**?

Trying inyMCE.execCommand also does not work.

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<div class=row><div class=col-md-6></div><div class=col-md-6></div></div><div class=row><div class=col-md-12></div></div>');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insertContent` is intended for plain text. `setContent` is intended for HTML. However `setContent` only allows you to add one level of HTML at a time. A way around this is to use `dom.add()`. This will allow you create a parent element and allows you add children nodes to it.

HTML

```
<form>
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

JS

```
//get inner element 'col-md-6'
//number is how many elements 
function getColMd6(number){
  var html = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
    html += '<div class="col-md-6"></div>';
  }
  return html;
}

//get inner element 'col-md-12'
function getColMd12(number){
  var html = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
    html += '<div class="col-md-12"></div>';
  }
  return html;
}   

tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea'
});

//Last parameter lets you specify extra inner html
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.add(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody(), 'div', {class: 'row'}, getColMd6(2));//or just plain html string at last param
tinymce.activeEditor.dom.add(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody(), 'div', {class: 'row'}, getColMd12(1));//or just plain html string at last param
```

Here is a example of it working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k0yc1zLt/1/)

Comment: I've been trying to learn more about this and just wanted to note that `insertContent` does seem to at least work to insert, say, an `img` tag. `setContent` is completely overwriting the contents of the `textarea`.